# Problems extend change_form.html in django admin

Tags: django, templates, django-admin, customization

I'm trying to extend the change_form.html template of one of my models to include some information on the page. I've read the django documentation in
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template

The problem is that is occurring:

> NoReverseMatch at /contas_pagar/pagamento/2/
>   Reverse for 'app_list' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'app_label': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P\w+)/$']

I'm using Django 1.6.5 with Django-Suit 0.2.12

The error image:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/80415688/error_app_django.PNG

in `my_project/my_app/templates/admin/my_app/my_model/change_form.html`

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
```

in `my_project/urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^contas_pagar/pagamento/(?P<id_parcela>\d+)/$',
                             'contas_pagar.views.retorna_pagamentos_parcela'),
    # django urls
    url(r'^doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'', include(admin.site.urls)),)
```

in `my_project/views.py`

```
def return_id(request, id):
    data = { 'test': 'test', }
    return render_to_response('admin/my_app/my_model/change_form.html', data,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve?

**UPDATE:**
I made some changes to the code.
The view is in my class ModelAdmin.

in my_project/my_app/templates/admin/my_app/my_model/change_form.html:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block after_field_sets %}{{ block.super }}
    <h2>{{ test }}</h2>
{% endblock %}
```

in my_project/my_app/admin.py:

```
class PagamentoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
form = PagamentoForm
model = Pagamento
list_display = ('id', 'parcelas_contas_pagar', 'data', 'valor')

def get_urls(self):
    urls = super(PagamentoAdmin, self).get_urls()
    my_urls = patterns('',
        (r'(?P<id_parcela>\d+)/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.retorna_pagamentos_parcela)),
    )
    return my_urls + urls

def retorna_pagamentos_parcela(self, request, id_parcela):
    data = {
        'test': test,
        'opts': self.model._meta,
        'app_label': self.model._meta.app_label, 
        'change': True,
        'add': False,
        'is_popup': False,
        'save_as': False,
        'has_delete_permission': False,
        'has_add_permission': False,
        'has_change_permission': True
    }
    return render_to_response('admin/contas_pagar/pagamento/change_form.html', data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Not appear more errors. Just is not displaying the fields of my class Admin.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`change_form.html` contains the following url tag:

```
{% url 'admin:app_list' app_label=opts.app_label %}
```

So you should pass the `opts` variable to the template context:

```
data = {'test': 'test',
        'opts': MyModel._meta}
```

**UPDATE**: The `change_form.html` template uses the `{% submit_row %}` template tag which requires some other context variables so the `data` dictionary should be like this:

```
data = {'test': 'test',
        'opts': MyModel._meta,    
        'change': True,
        'is_popup': False,
        'save_as': False,
        'has_delete_permission': False,
        'has_add_permission': False,
        'has_change_permission': False}
```

Comment: Hello friend, thanks for your response.
I made the change in my view.py.

He spent esso error ... But then there was another error ...

see [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/80415688/error_change_django.PNG)

I could not find anything about it.
Any idea of this error?

Comment: Amazing @catavaran,  
That was the problem, it was necessary to pass some variables there is more to the context :)  

But if you can help me with one last question ... I tried to do after your reply and I did not succeed ... The fields of my form was not rendered along with my customization. They simply do not appear.  

I need to provide some more variable in the context? extend some method of ModelAdmin?

Comment: Show your view and template.

Comment: Hi @catavaran, sorry for the delay. I updated my code in the post.

Comment: If you are trying to show the full change form then you have to pass much more (~10) context vars.  But I think it is a wrong way to do it.  The proper way is to override the `change_view()`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view

Comment: I understand @catavaran, okay, I'll search on change_view. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

This is caused most likely because you have a `{% url %}` tag that is trying to link to the app_list. It could be in your admin/form_change.html or in some other included/extended template.

This is **usually** caused by context that is not passed correctly such as if you have a tag that looks like `{% url 'app_list' %}` or `{% url 'app_list' var %}` and the `var` is empty.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my friend.
Lacked move to the context opts variable.

But still is showing the error said in answer I gave to @catavaran.
Do you have any idea what can be?

Answer (score -1):

I know it is late answer but for those who is struggle with that now like me, it is because of {% for fieldset in **adminform** %} adminform - is a form passed as context in change_form.html, however I currently have no idea how to pass it in my extension... Appreciate any comments.